# What is a "constant best fit"?

Tags: self-study, modeling, terminology, model

I'm working on this homework problem:

**Text of problem**

In Question 7, you fitted a simple linear regression model $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$, where $\varepsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ are i.i.d., to five different datasets.

For each of these five datasets,

(i) find the best-fit estimator for $\sigma^2$,

(ii) find 95% confidence intervals for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ (you may use the fact that $t_{1,0.975}\approx12.71$),

(iii) find a $p$-value for the hypothesis test of $H_0:\beta_1=0$ against $H_1:\beta_1\neq0$ in the form $P(F_{?;?}>?)$ where the question marks are to be filled-in,

(iv) draw a scatter-plot of the data and super-impose a line for both the best-fit linear relationship and the best-fit constant relationship. Don't use R for any of this!

**Source of problem**

Unpublished course notes for a statistics module of a second-year university mathematics course. This homework is not assessed and does not contribute to any grade.

**My question**

Does the "best-fit constant relationship" mean the line given by setting $\beta_1=0$ or the line given by the arithmetic mean of the data? The latter looks like a better fit, but doesn't seem to follow naturally from part (iii).

*My plot, setting $\beta_1=0$*:
[image]

*My plot, using the arithmetic mean*:
[image]

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the [tag:self-study] tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Where does this homework problem come from?  Eg, is it from a textbook that can be cited?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Done.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica On further reflection, I know the answer. If anyone has a preference, I can leave the question up or delete it.

Comment: It is your choice.  Since it doesn't have an upvoted answer, you can delete it.  Alternatively, you can post (& accept, if you like) your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP answering own question. On reflection, I think "setting $\beta_1=0$" implies recalculating $\beta_0$ in the reduced model, which produces the arithmetic mean, which is the constant best-fit relationship. If this is right then the lower graph is correct.

Comment: Almost certainly, this is what they were after.